# Extract year from string row in file text and move torrent to relative folder reordered by year

Tags: powershell, batch-processing

Question is tricky because is an evolution of my previously question.

To move torrent in folders I use this powershell script

```
$ToFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\to"
$FromFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\From"

#Create the sample folder on your desktop
#This line can be commented out if your ToFolder exists
New-Item $ToFolder -ItemType directory -Force

GCI -Path $FromFolder *.torrent | % {
    if ($_.Name -match "(19|20)\d{2}") {

        #Check to see if year folder already exists at the destination
        #If not then create a folder based on this year
        if (!(Test-Path "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])")) {
            New-Item -Path "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])" -ItemType directory
        }

        #Transfer the matching file to its new folder
        #Can be changed to Move-Item if happy with the results
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])" -Force
    }
}
```

but in my NEW situation I must extract year from file text *.txt*

Example list of file *.torrent* inside a folder

```
Caccia Spietata.torrent
Caccia Zero terrore del Pacifico.torrent
Caccia.A.Ottobre.Rosso.torrent
Cacciatore Bianco Cuore Nero.torrent
Cacciatore di Ex.torrent
Cacciatori Di Zombie.torrent
```

Example of string list in file text

```
Caccia grossa a casa di Topolino (2006)
Caccia selvaggia [HD] (1981)
Caccia spietata (2006)
Cacciatori Di Zombie (2005)
```

What script must do ?

**A.** extract year from string in file text (every string is on a single row because file text is a *list*)

***N.B*** *script should compare between torrent files names and strings in file text list.*

```
Caccia spietata (2006)
```

Extract year is possibile only for equal text or very very similar text like

```
Caccia Spietata.torrent
Caccia spietata (2006)
```

If I have

```
caccia.spietata.torrent
caccia SPiETata (2006)
```

this is for me very similar strings.

**B.** Make folder

```
2006
```

**C.** Move torrent

```
Caccia Spietata.torrent
```

into folder `2006`

I want this solution because I have many .torrent file name without year so I must reorder them correctly by year.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be related copyright infringement. Torrents named as "Hunt for Red October" and "Seraphim Falls" refer to commercial content.

Comment: it's just examples, not real torrent files ! This is not commercial content ! Where do you see torrent files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hurdle is parsing dates and names out of the string file. You then add them to a hash of movie name strings.

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}
$movies
```

Once you have the movie names and dates separate, you loop through each movie and create a folder if it does not exist.

```
foreach($movie in $movies){
$movie.date
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
```

After that, you can split the name into key words based on whitespace.

```
$words = $movie.name -split '\s'
$words
```

Below is as far as I've gotten during a break of mine. The next step is a bit complicated seeming, as you have to then match the torrent files to the object in the hash based on keywords. It will be hard to construct such a filter without access to the raw data. My first thought would be to match based on `fileName.torrent -like "*word*"`, but it looks like there are a ton of duplicate words. The next option is to match on multiple words, or maybe only use words that are not common (exclude "caccia", articles, etc). Either way, that should move you a bit closer to your goal. Maybe someone else can help finish, or I can revisit it during another break.

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}
$movies

foreach($movie in $movies){
$movie.date
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = $movie.name -split '\s'
$words
#this is as far as I got
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've added a bit that we talked about in comments. Most of the changes are at the bottom of the script.

```
$movies = @()
(get-content $Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
write-host $date
write-host $name

$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}
#no significant changes were made above this point
$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach($movie in $movies){
$datePath = "$Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
#this is as far as I got last time; most of the changes are below, though I did change 
#just a bit above

#this sets a number of words which needs to match. Currently, it has to match 
#on all words. If you wanted, you set it to a static number (2)
#     or do something like $words.count -1. There is a commented-out example of 
#such a solution.
$significant = $words.Count
#if($words.Count -eq 1){$significant = 1}
#else{$significant = ($words.Count - 1)

# here you loop through the torrentfiles, finding files whose base names have a 
#significant number of matching words with the string
 foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
 $matchingWords = 0
  foreach($word in $words){
   if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
    $matchingWords += 1
   }
  }
  if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
  $_ | Move-Item -Destination $datePath
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: mmm... seems good but with this script I have empty folder only but years are correctly extracted from file text :) But why is difficult to match, for example, `Caccia Spietata.torrent` with `caccia.spietata (2006)` string hash in file text ? Is possibile to match more of one word (2-4 words) between file name torrent and string to avoid duplicates ?

Comment: multiple words seems better solution but sometimes words are separates with dot (caccia`.`spietata) or underscore (caccia`_`spietata) or I have some apexes (Carlito`’`s) but I simply edit this with editor if it is too complex overcome the punctuation so.. `Carlito's` become `Carlito s`

Comment: The big question will be: how similar are the titles? If every word in the string will be includced in the .torrent filename, it won't be THAT hard.I'll update my answer with such a case.   ||||    If some of the strings contain words that aren't in the filename, it will be much more difficult. Again, I'll change my answer shortly, and then you can try that before making a final decision.

Comment: Torrent list example http://pastebin.com/NyD7hrwK and relative file list http://pastebin.com/1n5qPNLq . We have also many files not listened in text list

Comment: I just added an update with some more code. Looking at your lists, the ability to match words is a bit beyond me. I've taken you as far as I can. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, i post this question like new inserting your code. For the moment I accept your answer like definitive.

Comment: just a thing. with `$Path` script don't work for me, i replace with `C:\Path` is correct ? Is normal this message http://i.imgur.com/U7bcAvu.png ?

Comment: Error are `System.ArgumentiException Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null`. I use this script, please tell me if is correct http://pastebin.com/Dcrzi9xH. Seems that script never stop !